# How to send data html to adf jasf page

Tags: jsf

I could not pass parameter from html page to adf jsf page. for that i used jquery .but when my jsf page get Load i got following error
"ADF_FACES-30179:For more information, please see the server's error log for an entry beginning with: The UIViewRoot is null. Fatal exception during PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1." and for html page i used plsql htp package in smtp package so html link displayed in email So how i passed parameter from htp.package to adf jsf`enter code here` page?

My jsf Page File Code is

```
    <af:form id="f1">



   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["ECODE"] != null ) {
            var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
            data += "<b>EMPCODE:</b> " + queryString["ECODE"];
            $("#lblData").HTML(data);

             }
    });
```

```
   <af:inputText id="it1" autoSubmit="true" clientComponent="true" label="To Set Path" autoComplete="on"
                 autoTab="true">




   </af:inputText>

    </af:form>






</af:document>
```